# Laravel mysql avg() function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, average

I am using Laravel on developing my new app. I have initiated average function on a rating column in my database table and now I am just curious how could I make the average value from "3.3333" into "3.3".

```
$rating = Rating::avg('value');
echo $rating;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use php's inbuilt functions for rounding. In this case, you want a precision of one, so `round($rating, 1)`. For more info, please see the docs: http://php.net/round

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **round** it is inbuild PHP function and if you wish to round whatever result of laravel eloquent query result try code bellow

```
$rating=round(Rating::avg('value'),1)
```

if you want to round the value into the first *decimal point then use 1 inside round function after the comma*, likewise, you can increase the number with the preference you want to round a number.